# jQuery logic : Travesing elements and fading them in?

Tags: jquery, arrays, logic, traversal

Call for jQuery experts :)

http://s3.postimage.org/nb2mm7u2/download.png

Here is what I need. I need each blocks to fade in one by one. The fade-in order should be :

- First Blue element
- Second Blue element

  - Top-1 & Bottom-1 Green element (together)
  - Top-2 & Bottom-2 Green element (together)
  - Top-3 & Bottom-3 Green element (together)
- Third Blue element
- Fourth Blue element

  - Top-1 & Bottom-1 Green element (together)
  - Top-2 & Bottom-2 Green element (together)
- Fifth Blue element

PS: Initially everything will be hidden, and then in-order everything appears to make this final shape.

Solve here : HTML/CSS Code on JSBIN : http://jsbin.com/ogehoj/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Have you even tried implementing that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You could try selecting the elements with :nth-child() (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/child-filter-selectors/) and comma to select multiple elements and call fadeIn giving it callback what to do when fade in is complete (fade in next elements).

Comment: Tried the same using class names, but really looking for a class-name free solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be nice to see some evidence that you tried before posting here. Have a look at http://jsbin.com/etised/4/edit.

In a nutshell;

- define the render sequence by adding `data-render-seq="x"` to the appropriate elements
- On load, group the elements by `.data('render-seq')`
- iterate in order, calling `.fadeToggle()` and incrementing a delay (if required)

I've assumed you are able to modify the html, and that you don't mind using another js lib ([underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/))

Comment: Hi Rob - Thanks a lot :) I have tried the same using "class-names" instead of "data-values" you used. But, your code is much organised. Never used underscore.js before. Thanks !